# How to read the LINQ statement as a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have to following LINQ code:

```
var variable1 = _entitiesContext.Table1
    .Include("Table2")
    .Include("Table3")
    .Include("Table4")
    .Join(_entitiesContext.Table2, t1 => t1.F_ID, t2 => t2.F_ID, (tbl1, tbl2) => new { tbl1, tbl2 })
    .SelectMany(j => j.tbl2.Table3.Select(t3 => new
        {
          j.tbl2.F_ID,
          j.tbl2.F_ZGP_No,
          j.tbl1.F_NAME,
          j.tbl1.K_CODE,
          t3.Table4.Name,
          t3.Table4.LEI,
        }))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(s => s.F_ID)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Name)
    .ToList();
```

How can I read it like a SQL statement? I don't understand the workflow about the `.Includes`.

Comment: "I don't understand the workflow about the Includes." ← See [Entity Framework - Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: However, `Include` does not do anything here because you are projecting into an anonymous type. Also `Include` is used in Linq to Entities, not Linq to Objects.

Comment: This LINQ statement was written to mimic a SQL statement, which is a bad idea to begin with. It's the *ORM*'s job to generate JOINS from entity relations. You should probably fix the entire context, create proper entities instead of tables, with proper relations defined in the entities and context instead of spreading them in every query. Right now, it's *really* hard to understand what this does.

Comment: If you really need a four-way join though, you should probably create a view and map a keyless entity to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your advice. I know it's hard to read. That's not my code, but I want to understand it like a SQL statement.

Comment: Just log the query then, or use the database's profiler or tracing mechanism to capture the query. You can also log the query using your ORM's logging mechanisms. You still haven't explained *what* ORM you use. EF? EF Core? NHibernate?  Instead of understanding this though, it's better to fix it.

Comment: Besides, that query is incomplete - there's no `Join` between the other tables and `Table3` so `j.tbl2.Table3` would only work if there already was a navigation property `Table3` on `Table2`. Same for `Table3` and `Table4`. The `Include` statements don't join anything, they are used for lazy loading.

Comment: So it's impossible to guess what the SQL will be just by looking at the query. Are the Table2-Table3 and Table3-Table4 relations 1-1? 1-Many? Is Table3 a many-to-many table perhaps? The SQL query is created by the ORM, not LINQ, and different relations can result in different types of joins (INNER, LEFT etc).